# Why is my thread function running twice?

Tags: c, posix, multithreading, pthreads

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* runfunc(void* arguments){
    printf("in run thread\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t pthread_id;

    pthread_create(&pthread_id, NULL, runfunc, NULL);

    printf("after pthread creation\n");

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -pthread intro.c
$ ./a.out
after pthread creation
in run thread
in run thread
$ ./a.out
after pthread creation
$
```

There are 4 types of outputs for this program on linux.

1. "after pthread creation" -> this output can be easily understood as before thread execution process completes and exits and deletes all threads.
2. "after pthread creation
   in                    " -> this output can also be understood as while process was exiting thread executed a little bit to print in
3. "in running thread
   after pthread creation" -> this output can also be easily understood
4. "after pthread creation
   in running thread
   in running thread" -> now i don't get why am i getting "in running thread" 2 times instead of once.

Linux implementation of threads is considered.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic: it's about C programming. You can ask programming questions on [so]. Be sure to post code, not a screenshot of code.

Comment: Your thread function is not run twice, this is the stdout buffer that is output twice. This looks like a race condition during `exit()` when the stdout buffer is flushed in the exiting main thread, while it is also flushed in runfunc. It might be a bug, I'm not sure. Anyway, just `pthread_join()` before exiting and this bug should go.