# C function prints twice, only called once with a thread

Tags: c, pthreads

So i ran into a situation in my operating systems course, where it seems as if a thread or function somehow runs twice even though it shouldn't. My teacher was as confounded as i was that this happened, and that it's reproducible. If i run it enough times, sure enough eventually it will produce the same result, where the message is printed twice.
Anyone have any idea why and how this is happening?

See code below

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *PrintMessage1()
{
    printf("message from thread1\n");
}

void *PrintMessage2()
{
    printf("this is thread2\n");
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t Thread1, Thread2;
    int ret;

    ret = pthread_create(&Thread1, NULL, PrintMessage1, NULL);
    if (ret) {printf("Thread1 creation error\n"); exit(1);}

    ret = pthread_create(&Thread2, NULL, PrintMessage2, NULL);
    if (ret) {printf("Thread2 creation error\n"); exit(2);}

    printf("this is main\n");
}
```

Below is the output i get occasionally. It happens with both thread 1 and thread 2.

```
this is main
message from thread1
message from thread1
```

I'm running it in Ubuntu 22.04. I use nano for editing and cc for compiling.

- cc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0

Comment: It seems your C library `printf` function is not thread safe. Can you post more details about the running environment?

Comment: Apart from anything else `pthread_create` expects your thread function to have the signature `void * PrintMessage1(void *arg)` -- so you probably have undefined behaviour.

Comment: It would have to be some very old and weird standard lib in that case... However, this isn't guaranteed to print anything but "this is main" and then quit, since you don't wait for the threads.

Comment: @chqrlie I added some additional information about my running environment. Please tell me specifically about any additional information you would like. Also please tell me if i'm misunderstanding the concept of "running environment".

Comment: @G.M. I have edited my thread functions, but the behavior remains the same.

Comment: @lundq Please don't "fix" your question by updating the source as suggested in answers. That renders posted answers obsolete and nonsensical. If the answer didn't solve the problem, well just leave it be. There might be multiple problems.

Answer (score 3):

Misc notes/code review:

- `printf` ought to be re-entrant since at least some 20 years back. If you have earlier versions still, from a time before POSIX settled, then all bets are off. I remember using pthreads back in school around year 2000 and back then the status of the standard libs in regards to thread safety was quite shaky.
- Since you don't wait for (join) the threads to finish, this might just print `this is main` and quit. That would be conforming behavior.
- Declaring a function returning `void*` without a `return` statement is wildly undefined behavior. Your compiler ought to tell you as much. Note that gcc is sloppy here and requires `-Wall -Wextra`. Whereas for example clang warns without getting prodded with a stick first. I'd call that a gcc bug.
- Empty parenthesis in C means "accept any argument" and it's an obsolete form since some decades back. Correctly declared functions look like `void func (void)`. However, pthreads require a callback in the form of `void* func (void*)`.

  The compatibility between `void* (*)()` and `void* (*)(void*)` is a "language-lawyer" topic of it's own, but regardless you *are* using the wrong function pointer formats.

There's no such thing as "I *almost* wrote the code correctly" in C programming :) So change to functions looking like this:

```
void* PrintMessage1 (void* arg)
{
  printf("message from thread1\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed review and answer. I changed my functions and the behavior of the program remains the same.

Comment: @lundq Please update the question with info about compiler version and target system version.

Comment: I updated with info about compiler version. I'm not sure what target system version means. I think my question may have been answered in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67864851/why-is-my-thread-function-running-twice

Comment: @lundq Yeah that one also suggests the cause to be some buggy C lib, like they used to be couple of decades back.

Comment: *Declaring a function returning `void*` without a return statement is wildly undefined behavior.* [Only if the value is "used" by the caller](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p12).  Which, for a function passed to `pthread_create()`, will happen because it would not be available via `pthread_join()` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- the thread functions should have the proper prototype: take a `void *` argument and return a pointer. Change them to this:

  ```
    void *PrintMessage1(void *arg) {
        printf("message from thread1\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    void *PrintMessage2(void *arg) {
        printf("this is thread2\n");
        return NULL;
    }
  ```
- you should wait for the threads to complete before exiting the `main` function.
- as commented by *@xienne* in [Why is my thread function running twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67864851/why-is-my-thread-function-running-twice) , there seems to be a race condition when flushing `stdout` that causes the buffer to be written twice to `stdout`. You could write to `stderr` instead or set `stdout` to be unbuffered to further investigate this problem, but the proper solution is to wait for the completion of the threads with `pthread_join()`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *PrintMessage1(void *arg) {
    printf("message from thread1\n");
    return NULL;
}

void *PrintMessage2(void *arg) {
    printf("this is thread2\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t Thread1, Thread2;
    int ret;

    ret = pthread_create(&Thread1, NULL, PrintMessage1, NULL);
    if (ret) {
        printf("Thread1 creation error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ret = pthread_create(&Thread2, NULL, PrintMessage2, NULL);
    if (ret) {
        printf("Thread2 creation error\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    printf("this is main\n");

    pthread_join(Thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(Thread2, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect that the failure to join the threads before terminating is indeed a significant contributor to the problem.  And of course, all bets are off when the thread functions have the wrong signature (as this produces UB).  On the other hand, without UB, the program's behavior would be non-conforming, failure to join notwithstanding.